# Having a variable accessible to multiple sidekiq workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I was taking a look at the following gem: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh. I noticed that it allows you to establish an ssh connection and pipe multiple commands through it. Pretty neat. However, I have a few concerns about the way I could implement this efficiently.

For example, I have multiple workers that are scheduled to do things via SSH, and right now it simple creates a brand new SSH call every single time it needs to run a command. It's a lot of overhead and coudl take awhile when running numerous commands.

With something like `net-ssh`, I'd be able to establish an SSH connection such as this (to my understanding at least):

```
@ssh_client = Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', password: "password")
```

However, it'd be nice if my sidekiq workers could use this object without having to build a new ssh session every single time it needs to run a remote command. Is there a way that I could store this object in ActiveRecord and call it freely amongst other workers?

Answer (score 1):

Each sidekiq worker generally runs in a separate thread, so you probably wouldn't want to do this. Since you're running things in the background, you shouldn't worry too much about establishing a new connection for every job that runs.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. The main reason for wanting to keep things running in a same connection is to avoid the latency build up that will come along with hundreds, if not thousands, of commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *could* do this with a shared connection pool across threads. `Net::SSH` definitely won't implement that for you though. There are a few gems out there that appear to implement connection pooling.

Just a heads up: threaded code is much more complex than non-threaded. You'll have to handle cases where connections/jobs time out and managing pool sizes, etc.